# Flex Sound extract and save mp3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, audio, mp3

I'm trying to rig up a basic mp3 cutter in Flash (using the Flex framework)

I have gotten so far:

```
var ba:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
sound.extract(ba, playEnd - playStart, playStart);
```

This extracts the relevant bytes from the `sound` object and stores them in `ba`

Then, I do this:

```
saveFile=new FileReference();
saveFile.save(ba, sound.id3.artist + " - " + sound.id3.songName + ".mp3");
```

The file saves properly, but it can not be played (Players say it is corrupted)

Any pointers as to how I can create a valid mp3 file from the byteArray obtained after the extraction?

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: I would imagine that the mp3 format needs more data to be set than just the sound bytes.

Comment: @J_A_X, I realised that, but is there any way I can encode the raw bytes into an mp3 file?

Comment: The only Flash based audio manipulation tool I know of is [AudioTools](http://www.audiotool.com/), but they've been working on this product for years to get it where it is.  I would recommend you do more research as to what is the spec for the mp3 file format and learn how to reproduce it using the direct bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written many articles on audio processing with Flash on my blog. Here is one that you might find helpful:

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/07/slice-tool-looper/

This article outlines how to use the microphone to record audio and also includes some info on saving audio files:

http://labs.makemachine.net/2011/04/record-visualize-save-microphone-input/

Comment: I checked out the slice-tool

I am slicing differently, using extract. It basically gives a ByteArray containing the relevant bytes. I already have a wavEncoder, but that encodes only 1 second of sound for some reason... Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the wave format to save your file rather the mp3, it will save you a lot of time. Just look up the wave format and make your own class. You can have a look at this guy's class (henke37 post) : http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=256774 which can give you a start on how to do it. 
If you want to play your sound back later on, you will need to make a wave loader though.